# Import XML data into SQLSERVER using TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2019

I have developed query to fetch XML file from a FTP path using OPENROWSET.
When I try to read the nodes data, the query gives no result.

I have consulted many blogs and material but unable to find success. Please see the reference screenshot of my TSQL which reads the xml correctly but when I select the output column it returns blank.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ws:Worker_Sync xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ws:Header>
        <ws:Version>v29.2</ws:Version>
        <ws:Prior_Entry_Time>2023-09-27T11:00:00.000-07:00</ws:Prior_Entry_Time>
        <ws:Current_Entry_Time>2023-09-27T12:00:00.000-07:00</ws:Current_Entry_Time>
        <ws:Prior_Effective_Time>2023-09-27T11:00:00.000-07:00</ws:Prior_Effective_Time>
        <ws:Current_Effective_Time>2023-09-27T12:00:00.000-07:00</ws:Current_Effective_Time>
        <ws:Full_File>false</ws:Full_File>
        <ws:Document_Retention_Policy>180</ws:Document_Retention_Policy>
        <ws:Worker_Count>931</ws:Worker_Count>
    </ws:Header>
    <ws:Worker>
        <ws:Summary>
            <ws:Employee_ID>220511967</ws:Employee_ID>
            <ws:Name>Jazmine Samujh</ws:Name>
        </ws:Summary>
        <ws:Eligibility>true</ws:Eligibility>
        <ws:Personal>
            <ws:Name_Data>
                <ws:Name_Type>Legal</ws:Name_Type>
                <ws:First_Name>Jazmine</ws:First_Name>
                <ws:Last_Name>Samujh</ws:Last_Name>
                <ws:Formatted_Name>Jazmine Samujh</ws:Formatted_Name>
                <ws:Reporting_Name>Samujh, Jazmine</ws:Reporting_Name>
            </ws:Name_Data>
            <ws:Name_Data>
                <ws:Name_Type>Preferred</ws:Name_Type>
                <ws:First_Name>Jazmine</ws:First_Name>
                <ws:Last_Name>Samujh</ws:Last_Name>
                <ws:Formatted_Name>Jazmine Samujh</ws:Formatted_Name>
                <ws:Reporting_Name>Samujh, Jazmine</ws:Reporting_Name>
            </ws:Name_Data>
            <ws:Gender>Global_Female</ws:Gender>
            <ws:Birth_Date>1980-12-04-08:00</ws:Birth_Date>
            <ws:Address_Data>
                <ws:Address_Type>HOME</ws:Address_Type>
                <ws:Address_Is_Public>false</ws:Address_Is_Public>
                <ws:Is_Primary>true</ws:Is_Primary>
                <ws:Address_Line_Data ws:Label="Address Line 1"
                                      ws:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">406 Avalon
                    Dr.</ws:Address_Line_Data>
                <ws:Municipality>South San Francisc</ws:Municipality>
                <ws:Region>California</ws:Region>
                <ws:Postal_Code>94080</ws:Postal_Code>
                <ws:Country>US</ws:Country>
            </ws:Address_Data>
            <ws:Address_Data>
                <ws:Address_Type>WORK</ws:Address_Type>
                <ws:Address_Is_Public>true</ws:Address_Is_Public>
                <ws:Is_Primary>true</ws:Is_Primary>
                <ws:Address_Line_Data ws:Label="Address Line 1"
                                      ws:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">850 Cherry
                    Avenue</ws:Address_Line_Data>
                <ws:Municipality>San Bruno</ws:Municipality>
                <ws:Region>California</ws:Region>
                <ws:Postal_Code>94066-3031</ws:Postal_Code>
                <ws:Country>US</ws:Country>
                <ws:Address_Usage>Mailing_Postal</ws:Address_Usage>
            </ws:Address_Data>
            <ws:Phone_Data>
                <ws:Phone_Type>HOME</ws:Phone_Type>
                <ws:Phone_Device_Type>Global_Not_Specified</ws:Phone_Device_Type>
                <ws:Phone_Is_Public>false</ws:Phone_Is_Public>
                <ws:Is_Primary>true</ws:Is_Primary>
                <ws:Formatted_Phone_Number>+1 650 9225273</ws:Formatted_Phone_Number>
                <ws:International_Phone_Code>1</ws:International_Phone_Code>
                <ws:Phone_Area_Code>650</ws:Phone_Area_Code>
                <ws:Phone_Number>9225273</ws:Phone_Number>
                <!--2FA-->
                <ws:Enroll_MFA>Y</ws:Enroll_MFA>
                <ws:WD_Personal_Phone_Country_Code>1</ws:WD_Personal_Phone_Country_Code>
                <ws:WD_Personal_Phone_Number>6509225273</ws:WD_Personal_Phone_Number>
                <ws:WD_Personal_Email>Testme@gmail.com</ws:WD_Personal_Email>-->
                <!--2FA--></ws:Phone_Data>
            <ws:Phone_Data>
                <ws:Phone_Type>WORK</ws:Phone_Type>
                <ws:Phone_Device_Type>Global_Not_Specified</ws:Phone_Device_Type>
                <ws:Phone_Is_Public>true</ws:Phone_Is_Public>
                <ws:Is_Primary>true</ws:Is_Primary>
                <ws:Formatted_Phone_Number>+1 650 8375404</ws:Formatted_Phone_Number>
                <ws:International_Phone_Code>1</ws:International_Phone_Code>
                <ws:Phone_Area_Code>650</ws:Phone_Area_Code>
                <ws:Phone_Number>8375404</ws:Phone_Number>
            </ws:Phone_Data>
            <ws:Email_Data>
                <ws:Email_Type>WORK</ws:Email_Type>
                <ws:Email_Is_Public>true</ws:Email_Is_Public>
                <ws:Is_Primary>true</ws:Is_Primary>
                <ws:Email_Address>JSamujh@walmart.com</ws:Email_Address>
                <!--EmailForAll-->
                <ws:Email_Domain>walmart.com</ws:Email_Domain>
                <ws:Email_External_Flag>N</ws:Email_External_Flag>
                <ws:Email_Flag>Y</ws:Email_Flag>
                <!--EmailForAll-->
            </ws:Email_Data>
            <ws:Ethnicity>US_Asian_or_Pacific_Islander</ws:Ethnicity>
        </ws:Personal>
        <ws:Status>
            <ws:Employee_Status>Active</ws:Employee_Status>
            <ws:Active>true</ws:Active>
            <ws:Hire_Date>2015-12-21-08:00</ws:Hire_Date>
            <ws:Original_Hire_Date>2014-09-02-07:00</ws:Original_Hire_Date>
            <ws:Hire_Reason>Hire_Employee_Hire_Employee_Conversion</ws:Hire_Reason>
            <ws:Continuous_Service_Date>2015-12-21-08:00</ws:Continuous_Service_Date>
            <ws:First_Day_of_Work>2015-12-21-08:00</ws:First_Day_of_Work>
            <ws:Seniority_Date>2015-12-21-08:00</ws:Seniority_Date>
            <ws:Terminated>false</ws:Terminated>
            <ws:Has_International_Assignment>false</ws:Has_International_Assignment>
            <ws:Rehire>false</ws:Rehire>
        </ws:Status>
        <ws:Position>
            <ws:Operation>NONE</ws:Operation>
            <ws:Position_ID>P_0001816962</ws:Position_ID>
            <ws:Time_in_Job_Profile_Start_Date>2022-03-12-08:00</ws:Time_in_Job_Profile_Start_Date>
            <ws:Effective_Date>2021-12-18-08:00</ws:Effective_Date>
            <ws:Job_Effective_Date>2021-12-18-08:00</ws:Job_Effective_Date>
            <ws:Primary_Position>true</ws:Primary_Position>
            <ws:Position_Title>(USA) Analyst II, Talent Acquisition, Ecomm</ws:Position_Title>
            <ws:Business_Title>(USA) Analyst II, Talent Acquisition, Ecomm</ws:Business_Title>
            <ws:Worker_Type>Regular_Permanent</ws:Worker_Type>
            <ws:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</ws:Position_Time_Type>
            <ws:Job_Exempt>true</ws:Job_Exempt>
            <ws:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</ws:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
            <ws:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</ws:Default_Weekly_Hours>
            <ws:Full_Time_Equivalent_Percentage>100.00</ws:Full_Time_Equivalent_Percentage>
            <ws:Pay_Rate_Type>Global_Salaried</ws:Pay_Rate_Type>
            <ws:Job_Classification_Data>
                <ws:Job_Classification>JAID_HRE13058</ws:Job_Classification>
            </ws:Job_Classification_Data>
            <ws:Organization_Data>
                <ws:Operation>NONE</ws:Operation>
                <ws:Organization>A110</ws:Organization>
                <ws:Organization_Type>Company</ws:Organization_Type>
            </ws:Organization_Data>
            <ws:Organization_Data>
                <ws:Operation>NONE</ws:Operation>
                <ws:Organization>US11095</ws:Organization>
                <ws:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</ws:Organization_Type>
            </ws:Organization_Data>
            <ws:Organization_Data>
                <ws:Operation>NONE</ws:Operation>
                <ws:Organization>USA - Bi-weekly_CA</ws:Organization>
                <ws:Organization_Type>Pay_Group</ws:Organization_Type>
            </ws:Organization_Data>
            <ws:Organization_Data>
                <ws:Operation>NONE</ws:Operation>
                <ws:Organization>Sup_0000039529</ws:Organization>
            </ws:Organization_Data>
        </ws:Position>
    </ws:Worker>
</ws:Worker_Sync>
```

**TSQL (inner select works fine, outer return empty column):**

```
select MY_XML.phrase.query('phrase').value('.' , 'VARCHAR(200)')
FROM (
SELECT CAST ( MY_XML as xml) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\Test\version.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
) AS T(MY_XML)
CROSS APPLYMY_XML.nodes('phrases/phrase') AS MY_XML(phrase);
```

I consulted help from blogs i.e.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5707/simple-way-to-import-xml-data-into-sql-server-with-tsql/

Comment: Please copy and paste the SQL text in, using an image in this case is just silly.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL, i.e. CREATE table(s) T-SQL statements. 
(2) Well-formed XML file sample as a text. 
(3) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account XML namespaces. It is done via `XMLNAMESPACES()` clause.

All XML elements in the file are bound to the `xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync"` namespace.

Check it out.

**SQL**

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:com.workday/workersync')
SELECT c.value('(Version/text())[1]' , 'VARCHAR(200)') AS Version
    , c.value('(Document_Retention_Policy/text())[1]' , 'INT') AS Document_Retention_Policy
    , c.value('(Worker_Count/text())[1]' , 'INT') AS Worker_Count
FROM (
    SELECT TRY_CAST(MY_XML as XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\Test\version.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
) AS T(MY_XML)
CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('/Worker_Sync/Header') AS MY_XML(c);
```

**Output**

| Version | Document_Retention_Policy | Worker_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v29.2 | 180 | 931 |

Comment: Let me try it, for a large xml (like one in the link) , how to read the tags dynamically rather than statically defining a fixed tag .  Like in above details what if we need phrases/phrase and another object like contact/person.

Comment: Actual XML file link:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/14wbf8LZgIOil7NCAa3UsSG5vukhnURGu/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: So, what data you need to retrieve from the real XML? Please edit your original question, and provide the desired output.

Comment: Sir, it works even better than my Expectations.

Comment: Can u please advise how to dynamically get the columns from node tags e.g. if there are more than 50 columns it's tedious to individually mention each column in the final select statement.

Comment: It is impossible. All needed for shredding XML elements shall be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Noted please. Can we parse multiple files using Files Path, rather than explicitly harcoding One file name.

Comment: It possible via dynamic T-SQL. There is a request to Microsoft to make it possible in the future versions: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/45f8e196-5e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Please up-vote my suggestion to Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0